# My Python code work on my MacBook Pro but not any other MacBooks

Tags: python

Everyone. I am a student who is new to python, I just wrote a script and it works pretty good on my MacBook but whenever I try to run it on other's MacBook it will give me an Error Message says

```
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+00A0.
```

I don't what happened even I tried to search online, can someone please help me?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import shutil
import psutil
import math
import MacTmp
import time
import urllib.request
import os

def check_disk_usage(disk):
    """Verifies that there's enough free space on disk"""
    du = shutil.disk_usage(disk)
    free = du.free / du.total * 100
    return free > 20
def check_cpu_usage():
    """Verifies that there's enough unused CPU"""
    usage = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    return usage < 75
def disk_amount(disk):
    """The amount of free disk"""
    am = shutil.disk_usage(disk)
    free = am.free / am.total * 100
    return math.floor(free)
def cpu_amount():
    """The amount of cpu usage"""
    used = psutil.cpu_percent(1)
    return math.floor(used)
def check_localhost():
  localhost = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
  return localhost == "127.0.0.1"

def internet_on():
        try:
            urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.google.com', timeout=2)
            return True
        except:
            return False

size = os.get_terminal_size()

while True:
    if not check_disk_usage('/'):
        print("No disk for use!")
    elif not check_cpu_usage():
        print("You are using too much CPU")
    elif not check_localhost():
        print("Not the LOCALHOST")
    elif internet_on() == False:
        print("No Internet Connection")
    elif check_localhost() and check_cpu_usage() and check_disk_usage('/'):
        print("Everything is OK")
        print("|Free Disk: " + str(disk_amount('/')) + "|" + "|CPU Usage: " + str(cpu_amount()) + "|" + "|CPU Temperature: " + str(MacTmp.CPU_Temp()) +"|Internet: " + str(internet_on()) + "|")
    time.sleep(5)
    if int(float(cpu_amount())) >= 75 or int(float(MacTmp.CPU_Temp())) >= 95:
        break
    elif int(size.lines > 70):
        os.system('cls||clear')
print("Too much CPU is using now or Your device is very hot!")
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are you transferring the program? And how are you running it? `U+00A0` is a non-breaking space. It probably shouldn't be in your source code at all.

Comment: So I just copied the code and sent to my friend using message and made a new python file, then I ran the code by Terminal.

Comment: Then something in the transfer process likely introduced a non-breaking space. I'm not sure what "using message" means, but that might be the issue. Try transferring any other way that's less likely to mangle its contents: as an email attachment, via FTP, using a proper version control system, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean the Messages app on Apple products, so basically I just sent him a message with code. So, should I try using Github to do it or is there any way I can use this code on my friends laptop? Thank you for the point btw.

Comment: I wouldn't trust a chat app to transfer code without "helpfully" changing it. But as I said earlier, there are lots of options: email attachment, Git, USB stick, etc.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see them at top, thank you so much for helping, let me take another try.